# Android Java: Add absolute positioned view on screen

Tags: java, android, layout, interface

Let's say I've got a whole interface with some Layouts, View-Objects and stuff and now I want to write a java method that adds a pop-up error message over all this layouts to the front.

I know that there is the possibility to add it to an existing layout (e.g. `main_layout`) this way:

```
main_layout.addView(error_layout);
```

But is there maybe a way to put it just independent from the other layouts on the interface?
Something like

```
UInterface.addView(error_layout);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the root layout of your activity

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```